# mixed up color in plotly mesh

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I've been trying to plot a 3d mesh with colors in `plotly` and but the face colors keep being assigned incorrectly.

```
library(plotly)
library(Rvcg)

# example mesh
plyFile <- 
"https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c3bcbr6y9lidggg/AAD2cWFZEZczBIMXT0vdyGoia?dl=0?
raw=1"
download.file(plyFile, "Ellipsoid_colour.ply")

# plot 3d mesh
mesh <-vcgImport("Ellipsoid_colour.ply", readcolor = TRUE)
facecolor <- mesh$material
plot_ly(
  x = mesh$vb[1, ], y = mesh$vb[2, ], z = mesh$vb[3, ],
  i = mesh$it[1, ] - 1, j = mesh$it[2, ] - 1, k = mesh$it[3, ] - 1,
  facecolor = toRGB(facecolor$color),
  type = "mesh3d"
)
```

It should be like this-
[image]
But displays as this-
[image]
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: can't load plyFile

Comment: `facecolor$color` is a `3 x 3472` char matrix. Try using for example: `facecolor = toRGB(facecolor$color[3,])`